# ¿Que devuelve deletesync? Xamarin con Azure

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure, xamarin.forms

Buenas a todos chicos. Necesito saber que función o método devuelve el código que se genera al borrar un registro de la base de datos. El método que estoy usando es "DeleteAsync" de Azure. Necesitaria saber lo mismo para otras operaciones (insertAsync, etc). A continuación expongo mi código

```
void delete_click_button(object sender, EventArgs a) {
    if (ID != "") { 
        App.AzureService.MetodoDelete(ID); 
        //Si devuelve el codigo correcto....{
        DisplayAlert("Warning", "Eliminado satisfactoriamente", "Back");
             Navigation.PopAsync();
     }
         //Si devuelve codigo de error....
     {
            //display message
     }
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Esto te ayudará :D
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Net.Http.HttpClient.DeleteAsync/p/System.String/

Answer (score 0):

Si es IMobileServiceSyncTable, DeleteAsync devuelve un Task, es decir es esperable, pero solo eso, así que a efectos prácticos no devuelve nada.

Comment: ¿Te sirvió esta información?